# python sphinx settings to toggle line wrap in code-block

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-sphinx, word-wrap

Is it possible to add a button (similar to the copybutton of [sphinx_copybutton](https://sphinx-copybutton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to toggle line wrap in code blocks?

This toggle feature can be seen in many places such as [lazyvim plugin-in doc](https://www.lazyvim.org/configuration/plugins)(narrow you brower width and hover over code blocks to see the button)

[lazyvim plugin-in doc screen-shot, no reputation to post image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ4JE.png)

I tried to add .js and .css file to create button, but the button location is not inside the code block and nothing changed when clicking the button. Either my settings went wrong somewhere or it is not possible at all.

[failed toggle button example, no reputation to post image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X96Rn.png)

index.rst

```
Welcome to playground's documentation!
======================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

.. rst-class:: code-block

   .. code-block:: python

      def hello_world():
          print("Hello, world!")

   .. raw:: html

      <button class="toggle-button">toggle line wrap</button>
```

styles.css

```css
/* styles.css */
.wrap-lines .code-block {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* styles.css */
.toggle-button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

code_wrap_toggle.js

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-button");

    toggleButtons.forEach(function (button) {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            const codeBlock = button.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
            codeBlock.classList.toggle("wrap-lines");
        });
    });
});
```

I added this to the end of conf.py

```py
html_static_path = ['_static']
html_js_files = ["code_wrap_toggle.js"]
html_css_files = ["styles.css"]

def my_visit_line_block(self, node):
    self.new_state(indent=0)
    self.lineblocklevel += 1

def setup(app):
    from sphinx.writers.text import TextTranslator
    TextTranslator.visit_line_block = my_visit_line_block
```

Comment: Clearly it is possible, as lazyvim docs provide a working demonstration of the feature. You will need to replicate their JS and CSS in your project, and you have not yet done that.

Comment: Thank you, @StevePiercy, could you please offer an example? I do not know how to replicate their JS and CSS

Comment: Sorry, but, no, I have no idea to satisfy your requirements. The example you seek is in lazyvim docs. Check their source repository for implementation details.